# Is it safe to use this weird lifepo4 charger

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, lifepo4

I have an 8S LiFePO4 battery pack which I tried to charge using my suspicious lithium battery charger. The charger applied a voltage slightly higher than the battery voltage at any moment to charge it along with 1.5 A of current. For example, if the battery was at 26.2 V the charger applied 26.5 V and 1.5 A, and the voltage increased in the same proportion as the battery voltage increased. This was constant current charging.

The thing is, the charger cut off the charging while my battery was only 85-90% charged(26.6V) and never intiated the constant voltage charge. I just read somewhere that I need a charger which applies a constant voltage of 29.4 V to fully charge a 24 V LiFePO4 battery, not changing and slightly higher than battery voltage like the charger I used.

Did I damage my battery by charging it through a charger that doesn't fully charge my battery and give out constant 29.4 V? I may be just paranoid but it could be a serious thing. Can I continue using this charger in the long term which never initiates the CV charging? I'm fine with not utilising the remaining 10% SOC. I just want to make sure this kind of undercharging and this charger doesn't harm my battery in any way.

Note: I'm skeptical about buying a new charger because my current charger also lists 29.4V as maximum, but it never reaches beyond 27.4V while charging. I'm scared the new charger would do the same thing with my battery.

Comment: I've not heard of any battery getting damaged by not charging it enough. In fact, usually this is *good* for the battery and helps it last longer. The downside is that the battery has less charge in it.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661339/did-i-destroy-my-lifepo4-battery-pack-by-charging-it-using-the-wrong-charger

Answer (score 1):

Even if the device have a balancer included, then it is the best method do load the device only to a voltage close to the point were the voltage is rising (3.425V ~ 95% SOC) and then it will take a lot of time till the balancer is doing his job, because the balancing current is mostly very low.

You should not hold the voltage of the cell at 3.65V for a long time!

The best method is to use only the flat voltage zone, so do not go fare over 3.425V and not under ~3.25V if it is possible. This will increase the endurance of the cells.